# How many confirmations will Bitcoin core wait before I can send my coins out?

Tags: confirmations, sending, sendtoaddress

Using Bitcoin core 0.14, how many confirmations do I have to wait before I can send the coins out?

Is there a method to wait X confirmations before sending coins out from specific addresses that have less than X confirmations?

Answer (score 1):

> Using Bitcoin core 0.14, how many confirmations do I have to wait before I can send the coins out?

Bitcoin Core will let you spend received money after 1 confirmation, and let you spend change (money leftover from a transaction you sent yourself) without confirmations.

If possible, it prefers using coins that have 6 confirmations.

> Is there a method to wait X confirmations before sending coins out from specific addresses that have less than X confirmations?

You'll have to do that manually, using `listunspent` and `createrawtransaction`.

Comment: seems to me that one is not enough

Comment: is this configurable anywhere (bitcoin.conf?)

Comment: No, there is no configuration option for this.

Comment: I tried it again and it appears that 2 confirmations is needed. Counting moment transaction appears in mined block as first confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

Minimum 1 confirmation needed to send Bitcoin fromaccount to address.

Example : bitcoin-cli sendfrom fromaccount tobitcoinaddress amount [minconf=1] [comment] [comment-to]

Reference: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list

Comment: Note that the account system in bitcoin core is deprecated, including `sendfrom`

Answer (score 0):

> do I have to wait before I can send the coins out?

no

> Is there a method to wait X confirmations

yes. there is CSV opcode. you can create p2sh-address for yourself and can not spend from it before several confirmations of any incoming funds. but ask yourself what a reason for such restricts?

Answer (score 0):

Your transaction would be added to block and broadcasted to other nodes if in miner's blockchain that btc belongs to you. Otherwise, there is no waiting time.

But if you are trying to spend a coinbase transaction (reward mined), you will have to wait for 100 confirmations.